# Using Git with Multiple Local Directories - VVV localhost and repos

Tags: wordpress, git, localhost, vagrant, symlink

I keep local copies of repos in `~/repos`

I also have a `~/Sites` directory

When I create a new localhost WordPress site (like the one I'm currently working on) via Varying Vagrant Vagrants it ends up in a directory like `~/Sites/vagrant-local/www/my-website/htdocs/`

Most of the work will be on the theme so that path ends up looking like: `~/Sites/vagrant-local/www/my-website/htdocs/wp-content/themes/my-theme`

Since I have a starter theme I work from I have `~/repos/my-theme` and without thinking it through I copied it into place (the location in the above paragraph) and ended up with nested git repos and credential problems (while I hear nested repos are possible, I do not want that level of complexity, I'm just starting to understand how to use git).

Forgive me if my terminology is off, using a localhost and the command line are fairly new to me.

I think what I want is a `symlink`. I want these 2 directories to function as if they are one directory (so that file changes propagate to both) so that my theme's repo stays in `~/repos/my-theme` but that I can use Varying Vagrant Vagrants for my localhost server so I can enjoy both a local machine and version control.

How would I set this up?

If a symlink isn't the right solution to this problem, what is?

Should I just `cp` the repo to the localhost theme location and then `rm -R .git`?

Comment: I am having a bit of difficulty understanding where your issue lies... if you could please help me understand better, I may be able to help. Are you concerned about having Repos within Repos ( sub modules )? It is possible to set up a shorter path for localhost for example `~/htcdocs` is a possible root so your work could exist at `~/htcdocs/site/wp-content/themes/yourtheme`

Comment: I found out later it's that I was nesting repos...so yes, I guess it would be sub-modules. I never found out how to do it correctly but a friend explained what it was. I'd use git to pull down (into `Sites`) Vagrant...probably after I forked it) then I'd `cd` into one of the wordpress instances and use git to install a theme I had on github, then maybe I'd use git to pull down something else I thought I wanted to add...doing commits and pushes frequently...to wherever it went. What's the correct way to do it as a sub-module? Thanks.